# Echo out string up to a certain point

Tags: php, html

So I have some text in my database that is reading like so:

```
This is my very first blog post, <b>Ever!</b>
<rm>
This content is after the rm and should not be seen on the home page. That would just make for too much info on the front home page. Don't you agree?
```

Right now this text is lying, how can I make the echo stop at the made up  tag?

I want it to stop at `This is my very first blog post, <b>Ever!</b>` or at the  tag.

I have the following code

```
<?php if($posts): ?>
        <?php foreach($posts as $post): ?>
            <h3><a href="/post/<?php echo $post->id; ?>"><?php echo $post->title; ?></a></h3>
            <span><?php echo $post->body; ?><span>
            <hr/>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
        <p>No Recent Posts</p>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: `list($string) = explode('<rm>', $post->body); echo $string;`

Comment: Thank you, @MarkBaker can you please post in an answer?

Comment: You don't "make echo stop". You change your string so only the bits you want to show up are passed on to echo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are echo'ing a db query from php. Please be more descriptive next time. If you have a string type returned from query, you can use the [substring function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php). This will cut the string at a certain point and only echo that amount.

Another alternative specific to your case is the [explode function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php). If your query is $string,

```
<h3><a href="/post/<?php echo $post->id; ?>"><?php list($post->title) = explode('<rm>', $post->body); echo $post->title; ?></a></h3>
```